# TCP and UDP routing in minikube without using hostNetwork

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I want to do tcp and udp port forwarding to non-http ports in minikube without having to set the hostNetwork to true on the ingress controller. I also want this to be done entirely with a kubernetes resource definition yaml files. I don't want to use minikube tunnel or anything or have to run anything outside of kubernetes. Please let me know if you have any questions or need further clarification.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, can't you just use a NodePort Service? That would assign a random port for your service in your minikube node with which you can reach your TCP and UDP services. Otherwise O guess you'll need an ingress controller that supports TCP/UDP proxying, for example nginx ingress controller

Comment: I want to expose port 53 because that is the default DNS service. I want to use my minikube ip as a DNS server on mac where I cannot change the default port to something other than 53. Your idea only works if I can have a non-standard port for a service.